# Передать referer через intent в браузер Android

Tags: android

Есть ли способ при переходе с приложения в браузер передать "referer" путь?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Суть такая, есть сайт, который отвечает на запросы только если в GET запросе в строке referer придет значение (так и должно быть, в этом суть), но при переходе по прямой ссылке этого не происходит.